# How to solve the svm fit error?

Tags: scikit-learn, save, classification, svm

I have to classify the executable files as malicious and non-malicious files.
I have created my own corpus Train. I have explained the errors below. The input file format is also given below. How can I get the presence of the features with their names in the respective file and save it to a text file as a dataset?How can I test multiple files simultaneously? I am new to the classification of n-grams, please help me to solve all these issues. Thanks in advance.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2 
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn import svm   
a = load_files('D:\Train') #contains two folders true(non malicious) and false(malicious). that is targets
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(4,4))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(a.data) 
B,c = X, a.target
b_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000).fit_transform(B, c)
clf = svm.SVC(gamma="auto", C=1.)
clf.fit(b_new,a.target)
y = vectorizer.transform(open('D:/data/PRE/chrome.txt'))
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
data = le.fit_transform(matrix)
data = data.reshape(1,-1)
print(clf.predict(data))
```

ERROR:

```
File "D:/spyder/corpus.py", line 59, in <module>
print(clf.predict(data))

ValueError: X.shape[1] = 482180 should be equal to 1000, the number of features at training time
```

INPUT FILE FORMAT(hex file)

```
90 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 00 00 00
BA 0E 00 B4 09 CD 21 B8 01 4C CD 21 54 68
20 70 72 6F 67 72 61 6D 20 63 61 6E 6E 6F
62 65 20 72 75 6E 20 69 6E 20 44 4F 53 20
64 65 2E 0D 0D 0A 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
94 01 36 82 FA 52 36 82 FA 52 36 82 FA 52
```

UPDATED CODE

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2 
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn import svm   
a = load_files('D:\Train') #contains two folders true(non malicious) and false(malicious). that is targets
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(4,4))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(a.data) 
B,c = X, a.target
ch2 = SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000)
X_train = ch2.fit_transform(B,c)
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X_train,a.target) 
y = vectorizer.transform(open('D:/data/PRE/chrome.txt')))
X_test = ch2.transform(y)
print(clf.predict(X_test))
```

OUTPUT

```
[1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
```

ISSUES
    I gave only one file as test set. That is all the contents are stored in the single array. Then how it is giving several 1's in the output. There should be only one 1. Another issue is that for any test data it is always giving an array of 1 as output. It is binary class and it does not return another class. What to do?

Comment: You are using different approaches for training and testing data. Test data should be transformed in the same way as training data is. Your train data has 1000 features, and your test data dont. Hence the error

Comment: Are you saying the transform method or feature selection method?

Comment: I am talking about `data` variable. You are using a new LabelEncoder() on it. Whereas you should only use those transformations on the test data which are fitted onto train data.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Vivek. I have changed my code. Please look at the updated code and say whether it is correct or not?

Comment: Help me with the further issues

Answer (score 0):

I solved one issue. To produce single 1 for a single file in the output. I just change the following lines of code below.

```
docs=['D:/data/PRE/office.txt']
y = vectorizer.transform(docs)
```